# Not able to authenticate using client certificate in Requests of python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the following code line to request a `HTTPS` url.

```
r = requests.get(
 'https://xxxx.xxx.xxx',
    cert='/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx.pem')
```

But it returns me this error:

```
SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I can load the certificate via command:

```
openssl x509 -in xxxx.pem -text -noout
```

and check the private key inside the certificate:

```
openssl rsa -in xxxx.pem -check
```

I don't know what is missing here to make this call work. The same request in chrome is working perfectly.

Thank you!
Kun

Answer (score 0):

If `'/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx.pem'` is a [CA cert](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) required to check certificate of `'https://xxxx.xxx.xxx'`, then you need to pass it to `requests` in param `verify`:

```
r = requests.get(
   'https://xxxx.xxx.xxx',
   verify='/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx.pem',
)
```

If it is a cert for [client verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates), you need to pass not only path to the cert, but also path to private key:

```
r = requests.get(
   'https://xxxx.xxx.xxx',
   cert=('/Users/xxxx/Documents/cert.pem', '/Users/xxxx/Documents/privkey.pem'),
)
```